# MonoDroid application drain batery faster?

Tags: xamarin.android

a MonoDroid application runs on Mono Runtime, but Dalvik VM is also loaded, ok?

And MonoDroid application use Java libraries over C# libraries, thus, to use a method, is
necessary two calls?

App -> c# -> JAVA

MonoDroid applications spends more batery?

Answer (score 4):

To a large extent, I think this borders on micro-optimization. Yes, there is some additional overhead in method calls due to JNI, but this should be fairly trivial in the grand scheme of things (as opposed to, say, XML processing, or image manipulation, or...). Furthermore, all of RAM will need to be powered anyway (that's how DRAM works, and I doubt they're using SRAM for RAM in these devices), so the fact that two VMs are loaded into memory shouldn't cause any additional battery use either.

CPU time will be a determining factor, but I highly doubt that JNI will be a significant contributor (lacking profiling data that suggests otherwise).